# Finder layout changed in "Recents"

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

Yesterday i noticed that my Finder's layout for the "Recents" tab changed out of the blue; my view options for Recents are "Group by: Kind" & "Sort by: Date Last Opened" for anyone's reference.

Before it used to display from top to bottom as: `Images, PDF Documents, Presentations`... currently now it's: `Presentations, PDF Documents, Images` ... The only contributing factor i could think of that may have caused this is when i restarted my computer well before i noticed the change; further restarts dont seem to change it back to the original layout it displayed.

Has anyone else noticed that their Recents tab in the Finder changed the layout/display as well? What exactly could have caused Finder to change its layout? Why did this change occur and is there a way to change it back?

Comment: You can observe that not only Recents has changed. The governing feature here is sort by "Kind". Right now I am looking in `finder.plist`.  Will update by tomorrow. You too can use https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/ to do the same. Make a copy for sure first. Also I am not affiliated with this product.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii ive always had "Sort by: Kind" enabled in the recents tab for Finder. The only thing is that the layout changed out of the blue the other day; i cant remember if it was after i restarted my computer or not unfortunately... but the details remain the same as to how it was to how it is now

Comment: Yes. I meant that the "kind" sort has something to do with the change, not the Recents.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii i get that, but why did the "Sort by: Kind" in the Recents tab change it's layout like that out of the blue? as i said it used to go "X, Y,  Z" and now its "Z, Y, X"